# Change the value of column based on quantity of equals rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['B668441DE83B', 'B668441DE83B', 'B668441DE83B', '89C26DEE41E2', '89C26DEE41E2'],
                   'desc': ['Car', 'Car', 'Bus', 'Bus', 'Bus'],
                   'quantity': [2, 2, 1, 3, 3]})
print(df, '\n')
```

```
             id desc  quantity
0  B668441DE83B  Car         2
1  B668441DE83B  Car         2
2  B668441DE83B  Bus         1
3  89C26DEE41E2  Bus         3
4  89C26DEE41E2  Bus         3
```

I need to change the value of `quantity` column to 1 if `quantity` value of row equals the actual quantity of rows, where columns `id` and `desc` are equals (row0 and row1 in this example).

Desired output:

```
             id desc  quantity
0  B668441DE83B  Car         1
1  B668441DE83B  Car         1
2  B668441DE83B  Bus         1
3  89C26DEE41E2  Bus         3
4  89C26DEE41E2  Bus         3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for count values per groups, compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` by original and last set `1` by mask:

```
mask = df.groupby(['id','desc'])['id'].transform('size').eq(df['quantity'])

df.loc[mask, 'quantity'] = 1
```

Or:

```
df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].mask(mask, 1)
```

---

```
print (df)
             id desc  quantity
0  B668441DE83B  Car         1
1  B668441DE83B  Car         1
2  B668441DE83B  Bus         1
3  89C26DEE41E2  Bus         3
4  89C26DEE41E2  Bus         3
```